# Azure App service connect to SQL Server on premise without hybrid connection

Tags: c#, web, azure-web-app-service, windows-server-2012

I have a Web API deployed to an Azure service app (2 nodes). I want to connect to an on-premise SQL Server 2016 database.

I get the message:

> Cannot connect to the database

I disabled the firewall on the on-premise SQL Server (to test), but it still is not working.

I can connect running the app on my PC connecting to the SQL Server (by ipnr), but not if I publish it to Azure (I checked the `web.config` in Azure, it is looking good). I am using an ipnr (in the connection string) to connect.

- .NET framework 4.5.2
- Entity Framework 4.6.3

It's already working with a hybrid connection, but that's limited to 25 connections, in my case, the app will be used by a lot of concurrent users, like 200 users, so I don't want a hybrid connection. I want a direct connection based on an ipnr and firewall settings. Or another solution.

Hybrid connection is working, but is limited to 25 connections. I have more concurrent users.

It must connect with the on-premise SQL Server database.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to connect to the internal IP address, which Azure is unable to connect to. Since it's internal. So only available *internally*.

Exposing an internal SQL Server to the internet is not just disabling the firewall on the server, which is a bad practice in general. There's more stuff you need to take care of, like port forwarding.

I think your best solution would be to create an [Azure Virtual Network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-overview) and connect to your on-premises database through that.

*By the way*:
Number of concurrent users does not necessarily mean number of connections. You probably have an *application* connecting to the database, not a *user*, right?

Comment: thanks rick for your quick answer.

1. it is a public ip address with a ip filtered firewall setting on port 1433.
I just disabled the firewall only for testing purpose.

2. I dont know how to make an azure virtual network with the on premise network, is that easy? I hope you can help me with a nice easy tutorial/instructions

3. yes i have a angular website that is requesting to the webapi. the webapi has a fixed database user account. Do you think i dont have a problem with the max 25 hybrid connections?